# 7zip command line archive folder in subfolder without the first subfolder inside the archive

Tags: command-line, 7-zip, archiving

having a folder structure like this:

```
archive.cmd
sub1.zip // create
sub2.zip // create
foos
   sub1
   sub2
```

I want to generate `sub1.zip` and `sub2.zip` inside the main folder.

the problem is that `sub1.zip` inside will contain `\foos\sub1\files` but I need `sub1\files`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it by adding `.` before the path

```
7z a sub1.zip .\foos\sub1
7z a sub2.zip .\foos\sub2
```

this creates `sub1.zip` that contains only `sub1` folder with its contents